# setInterval not working jquery

Tags: jquery

When i click and hold `down` the value should continually decrease until i `mouseup` or `mouseleave`.  Instead i have to keep on clicking down.  Here is is the jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/5mdwe/8/

```
$('#bid-down').live('mousedown',function() {

var button = $(this);
var number = $(this).parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val();
var newnumber = number.split('.');


button.data('interval2', setInterval(function (){

var on = button.attr('data-on');

if(newnumber[0]==2 && newnumber[1]==5) {
    alert('Minimum Bid($2.50)');
    }

if(on==1) {
    if(newnumber[0]>2) {
        if(newnumber[1]==0) {
        var first = parseInt(newnumber[0])-1;    
        var second = 9;    
        }
    }

    if(newnumber[1]==0) {
    var first = parseInt(newnumber[0])-1;    
    var second = 9;
    }

    if(newnumber[1]>0) {
    var first = newnumber[0];    
    var second = parseInt(newnumber[1])-1;    
    }

    if(first==2 && second==5) {
    button.attr('data-on','0');
    }

    var finalnumber = first+'.'+second;
    button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val(finalnumber);

}

}, 100));


}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {

clearInterval($(this).data('interval2'));
});
```

Comment: At first glance I don't see an obvious problem, though you did get carried away redeclaring the same variables with `var` inside your `if` statements, but I do wonder why you're using `.live()` for the mousedown but `.bind()` for the mouseup and mouseleave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interval is working perfectly. However you do not handle `number` and `newnumber` inside the `setInterval` functionality

if you add something like `console.log('down');` and then look in the error console of the browser, you can see that your `setInterval` is executing repeatedly

With your existing code you need to change a few lines see http://jsfiddle.net/5mdwe/23/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code lines to extract the number INSIDE the interval function

-OR-

set the value of number/newnumber at the end of the interval function.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mdwe/17/).